# iOS / Objective C Parse JSON get int

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've been trying unsuccessfully to parse this json:

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/pending_coins","value":20}]
```

I want the value of 20 so I can do

```
int quantity = jsonValue; //20
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
    NSArray *patch =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:anEvent.data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

    NSDictionary *dict = patch[0];

    NSLog(@"patch: %@", dict);

    NSInteger quantity = (NSInteger)[dict valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSLog(@"quantity: %ld",(long)quantity);

    if (quantity > 0) {
        NSLog(@"You earned %ld coins!",(long)quantity);
    }
```

I've tried both `objectForKey` and `valueForKey` and neither seems to get me what I'm looking for.

If I do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[patch valueForKey:@"value"]]` I get a value of 20 as a String, but `intValue` and `integerValue` on that don't seem to net me what I want.

Right now, the logs show this:
`quantity: -5764607523034234845`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I can't control the JSON or I'd just nix the outer array around the object.

Comment: `[[dict objectForKey:@"value"] integerValue]` should work.

Comment: Dah! You're a lifesaver. I knew I was close. Want to toss that in as an answer for a +1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer in a JSON dictionary will be mapped to an instance of `NSNumber` when deserialized, which has various methods on it to retrieve scalar values.

To get an `NSInteger` from the JSON you would do:

```
NSNumber *number = [dict objectForKey:@"value"];
NSInteger quantity = [number integerValue];
```